# Ubuntu 16.04 slows down, cpu max freq is low

Tags: 16.04, intel, cpu, temperature

I have two OS on my notebook. The first one is Ubuntu 12.04 and it is rather OK, but too old and damaged by my unexperienced actions (manual package installations, etc). The second one is Ubuntu 16.04. It was a fresh install (not upgrade) and I have installed many applications and libraries in it.

Suddenly I noticed that Ubuntu 16.04 slows down. Unity becomes choppy, all applications run slowly. It takes place once a while, especially after long period of working. (And especially when my friends, most of which are windows-users, are working with me.)

`cpufreq-info` says:

`cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.30 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.30 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.41 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.30 GHz:5,45%, 1.80 GHz:3,30%, 1.60 GHz:2,71%, 1.40 GHz:4,81%, 1.20 GHz:8,84%, 1000 MHz:17,69%, 800 MHz:57,20%  (276340)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.30 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.30 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.47 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.30 GHz:9,57%, 1.80 GHz:3,13%, 1.60 GHz:2,55%, 1.40 GHz:4,67%, 1.20 GHz:8,55%, 1000 MHz:16,73%, 800 MHz:54,80%  (256609)
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.30 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.30 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.41 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.30 GHz:8,27%, 1.80 GHz:3,19%, 1.60 GHz:2,57%, 1.40 GHz:4,60%, 1.20 GHz:8,56%, 1000 MHz:16,26%, 800 MHz:56,54%  (274971)
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.30 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.30 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.34 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.30 GHz:4,96%, 1.80 GHz:3,40%, 1.60 GHz:3,15%, 1.40 GHz:6,25%, 1.20 GHz:12,28%, 1000 MHz:15,64%, 800 MHz:54,31%  (303947)`

There could be different values instead of `1.40 GHz`, even `920 MHz` and `800 MHz`.

`intel_pstate` is disabled with `grub` option.

`dmesg | grep temperature` says

`[19065.630210] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2551)
[19065.630212] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2551)
[19065.630214] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2729)
[19065.630216] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2729)
[19065.630219] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2729)
[19065.630225] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2728)
[19065.641347] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[19065.641350] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[19065.641358] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[19065.641361] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[19065.641387] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[19065.641393] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[19783.068723] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2780)
[19783.068727] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2780)
[19783.068734] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2963)
[19783.068738] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2963)
[19783.068746] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2962)
[19783.068760] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2963)
[19783.078851] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[19783.078854] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[19783.078885] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[19783.078888] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[19783.078891] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[19783.078897] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal`

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/bios_limit` says

`2300000`

`sensors` says
```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +72.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:        +72.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:        +72.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +70.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +1.08 V  (min =  +0.83 V, max =  +1.08 V)
temp1:        +72.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

`/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` is manually set to `1`

`sudo modprobe acpi_cpufreq`
`lsmod | grep acpi_cpufreq`
says nothing

`sudo sh -c "echo 2300000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq"`
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`
has no effect

`uname -a` says
`Linux nicknout 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Switching governor doesn't matter.

Pluginn off the charger and replugging it back doesn't matter.

Sometimes low performance appears for several seconds, and then max freq restores to 2.3 GHz

Answer (score 0):

It was not actually a bug, it was reqular feature to avoid overheatting.
Ifi you really want to disable this (that is not recommended), just do:

`sudo killall thermald`

`thermald`  was introduced in Ubuntu 14.04